# How can I use ssh to cat to a file in a remote Linux directory if the directory doesn't exist yet?

Tags: ssh, authorized-keys

I'm trying to send the public id_rsa.pub file from my Mac to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys directory in my home directory at Linux servers so I can then access without logging in each time.

From my Mac Terminal I'm using this command:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@remoteserver 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

This works if the remote ~/.ssh directory already exists, but doesn't otherwise. In that case I have to first login to the remote server, create the .ssh directory, then logout, and then run the above command. After that I can ssh to the remote server without logging in.

I need to do this for a few dozen servers, so I was wondering if there was a way of modifying the above command to create the remote .ssh directory if it wasn't already present.

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Use `ssh-copy-id`

In general [`ssh-copy-id`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) takes care of nonexistent directory or file. Use it [if you can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25655450/10765659); do not reinvent the wheel.

---

#### Without `ssh-copy-id` (for whatever reason)

On the remote side you run commands in a shell. Run more commands. Make sure the extra commands don't consume stdin before `cat` does (use `</dev/null` if needed). Here neither `cd` nor `mkdir` uses stdin, so this should work:

```bsh
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@remoteserver '
   cd ~/ || exit
   mkdir -pm 700 .ssh
   cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys
   chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
'
```

Notes:

- `-p` makes `mkdir` not complain if `./.ssh` already exists as a directory.
- `-m 700` sets the right mode from the very beginning.

The code can be improved. My main point is you are not limited to a single `cat`.

Comment: I tried `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh-copy-id username@remoteserver 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'` but get an error `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: Too many arguments.  Expecting a target hostname`. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: I also tried `ssh-copy-id -i  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server` and got the error `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`.

Comment: Plain old `ssh-copy-id user@server` worked. Thanks!

Comment: `cd ~/` (more simply, `cd`) should be a no-op, as the working directory should already by the home directory.

Comment: You can also make this independent of the working directory; `mkdir -pm 700 ~/.ssh; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Also, the permissions on `authorized_keys` itself don't matter, so just `mkdir -pm 700 ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should do.